# How can I prove that the Cantor set is a Borel subset of [0,1]?

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory

How can I prove that the Cantor set $K$ is in $\mathfrak{B}$, where $\mathfrak{B}$ is the collection of Borel subsets of $[0,1]$ ?

Answer (score 6):

The Cantor set can quite easily be defined in terms of a countable intersection of open and closed sets. In each step you "remove the middle third of each part". Explicitly, you see that 
$$K = \bigcap_{i=1}^\infty\bigcap_{j=1}^{3^{i-1}-1}\left[0,\frac{3j+1}{3^i}\right]\cup \left[\frac{3j+2}{3^i}, 1\right]$$

Since $\mathfrak{B}$ consists of those sets which can be formed from countable unions, countable intersections, and complements of open (equivalently closed, because of complements) sets. Since we explicitly defined $K$ in terms of intersections and unions of closed sets, because intervals are closed, we have that $K$ must be Borel.

Answer (score 5):

Hint: Show that $K$ is closed.